# adding caption under figure for addplot

Tags: captions

How can I add caption under my function, for example `[Fig 1]`, and how can I refer to that figure?

My Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$\mu(x)$
    ]
    % invoke external gnuplot as
    % calculator:
    \addplot[smooth,samples=180,domain=0.0001:20] {1/(1+(1/x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `\begin{figure}\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\caption{Caption}\label{fig:figure}\end{figure}`?

Comment: I tried that and it just disappears when I add the figure tag..

Comment: Then we need a minimal document which shows the problem when compiled.

Answer (score 3):

You can put your plot inside `figure` environment and add the caption as usual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$\mu(x)$
    ]
    % invoke external gnuplot as
    % calculator:
    \addplot[smooth,samples=180,domain=0.0001:20] {1/(1+(1/x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{This is my plot}\label{fig:myplot}
  \end{figure}

  From \ref{fig:myplot} I don't get nothing.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the caption appears as "From ?? I don't get nothing"

Comment: @user28952: Did you compile the document twice?

Comment: It works now, but when I add abstract tag and some writing, the figure disappears, but it reappears if I remove the figure tags and just leave the tikzpicture tag without the caption.

Comment: ypu then should post a minimal example where the problem occurs.